# VS Entreprise 2015 (even with community) is missing the whole C# template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, missing-template

I had VS community 2015 installed in my PC but with few errors so I uninstalled it and installed the Enterprise version but that when I noticed that the whole C# template is missing so I did "Repair" but nothing was fixed I even delete it and it persists, I even tried to check for the templates when installing it but C# wasn't there.
I even tried to install the community version again but it won't work, really need your on this guys .

[image: The missing C# template when installing]

[image: Missing C# template]

Comment: it contains the program languages like english, french, ...

Comment: As far as I know, C# is always included. Maybe you need to reinstall the templates, could try something like 'devenv /installvstemplates'.

Comment: As said in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx, VB and C# are always installed. Your first screen shot here is surely because you have selected Custom from the previous step.

Comment: and as said in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0dd15332-7744-44ea-85a8-5ec6b36febcc/visual-studio-2015-missing-project-templates?forum=visualstudiogeneral, you should try: 
devenv /installvstemplates
devenv /ResetSettings.